# how to use env-var in parameters of custom tool

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

how can I use an env. var (e.g. `APP_HOME_DIR`) in the `Parameters` field dialogue of `Tool Properties` dialogue?
i.e. I've tried to use `$(APP_HOME_DIR)`, but then I cannot close the dialogue: *"Error: Unknown Macro command"*

to clarify - I'm talking about this dialogue: `Tools` -`Configure Tools...` - `Add...` (or `Edit`)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use an environment var (e.g. `APP_HOME_DIR`) in the Parameters field dialogue of Tool Properties dialogue?

The simple answer is that you cannot. The IDE does not expand environment variables before passing the arguments to the external process.

Comment: too bad - a workaround is to make a batch file instead and use the env var in the batch file: `explorer.exe /E,%APP_HOME_DIR%`

Comment: Yes, that will get it done. I tried using `%var_name%` but the IDE won't expand that.